# DSpace 6.2 Mirage 2 Artifact Preview Thumbnail Modification

Tags: jquery, css, sass, dspace

So I'm trying to modify the artifact preview thumbnails, i.e. size, padding, border, border color, on Mirage 2 and I can't seem to find the particular file to modify.

Quite simply i'm trying to get this:
[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDhwN.png)

To look like this:
[Eventual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZKze.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thumbnail styling is defined in these scss files.

1. https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/styles/classic_mirage_color_scheme/_general.scss#L410-L417
2. https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/styles/classic_mirage_color_scheme/_item-lists.scss#L17-L35

These files are compiled into the main.css in the Mirage2 build.

In your source directory, create a file _style.css in dspace\modules\xmlui-mirage2\src\main\webapp\themes\Mirage2\styles and add your overrides there.

See https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Mirage+2+Configuration+and+Customization#Mirage2ConfigurationandCustomization-Simplestylingcustomization for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly. I am also having trouble with the footer. I have managed to find where to customize the text content i.e the page_structure file but I can't seem to find the file in which to customize the styling or I could be doing it wrong.

Comment: @SamuelMwamburi, please post a new question about the footer and tag it as a dspace issue.